# Patch a Ruby Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, patch, monkeypatching

What is the best way to apply a simple patch to a Ruby gem in a Rails app?

Is it possible to keep the original gem code untouched?

Comment: Related: [How do you apply a patch to ruby on rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/930126/55075)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Just open the class, alias the method that has problems, and provide your own implementation of it. [This page](http://blog.jayfields.com/2006/12/ruby-alias-method-alternative.html) shows an example of this.

You can open that class from any class, provided you added the necessary includes. Physically, the original code will remain unchanged.